# Do people read the tag information before creating a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

As some of you may have noticed, over the last weeks I have been creating/updating the tags on the website.

I noticed that most of the time people don't seem to check the tag information when they create a question.

For example this question is using the **magento-1** tag: [Upgrade Magento 1.5 to 1.9 Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_App::getIsCacheLocked()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/91007/2380)

However in this tag info, it is specified:

> Do not use the tag when...
>
> - you have a problem in a Magento installation and assume the version is not important
> - you have a question related to updating between different Magento 1.x versions

If you make a search on the questions with this tag and with the keyword "update" or "upgrade" you can find a lot of questions which are, based on the tag information, using this tag where they should not.

So:

- do people read the tag info?
- in this particular tag case, what's the action that we should take? Update every questions using this tag where they should not? Update the tag to remove this "restriction" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as simple to answer as it is disappointing for tag wiki editors:

[image: stats screenshot]

Unlike other network sites, on this site the tag wikis don't have a history of being useful, so it's no wonder that they are not viewed more often. When did you see a link to a tag wiki as reference for more information the last time? Never? Right.

However, the **tag excerpt** is far more likely to be read as it shows up during tag autocompletion. So if users search for tags and not just blindly types them in, they will at least see the excerpt.

So IMHO it is a good idea to add a basic usage definition and references to alternative tags there.

Answer (score 4):

actually, I dont see why questions for install/update problems should not get a magento-1 tag. "Ignoring" of such "rules" is more showing, that the rules for this tag may not match reality and should therefore changed.